# Separating bound First and Surnames with a space using gsub in r

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a character vector where some First and Surnames are separated with a space and some are not. I need to separate with a space those character strings where First names and last names are not separated. Each names begins with a capital.

e.g. in

```
x <- c("John Lennon", "GeorgeHarrison", "RingoStarr")
```

I would like George and Ringo's names to be separated by a space while leaving John's as-is.

After looking on SO I tried

```
gsub("([[:upper:]][[:lower:]])", "\\1 \\2", x)
```

but that yielded

```
"Jo hn Le nnon" "Ri ngoSt arr"
```

To be honest I don't have a clue what I'm doing when it comes to regular expressions (Just bought a book on it a minute ago on Amazon but can't wait that long).

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PERL look-ahead:

```
gsub("([[:lower:]])(?=[[:upper:]])", "\\1 ", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "John Lennon"     "George Harrison" "Ringo Starr"
```

Explore this on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/93dnFM/1) for more, and read about look-around regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

---

Upon further inspection of your attempt, you made two crucial mistakes:

- You switched `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]`
- You captured only one group, when you really wanted to capture two groups

You can make slight changes to your own approach:

```
gsub("([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])", "\\1 \\2", x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelChirico. You say I made mistakes but really I just copy-pasted that syntax from another post in the hope that it would work, I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing :) I really need to learn Regex properly. It seems so useful.